# How to access a Solidity mapping from HardHat

Tags: solidity, javascript, hardhat

I have a mapping:

```js
mapping(bytes32 => string) requestToCharacterName;
```

I am trying to access it from HardHat as such:

```js
contract.requestToCharacterName(bytes32)
```

And receiving the following error:

```bash
 TypeError: contract.requestToCharacterName is not a function
```

What do I need to do in HardHat to properly access this mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every variable is actually just a `view` function, however, if no visibility is specified, it will default to `internal` (per the [solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/contracts.html?highlight=visibility#visibility-and-getters)).

You cannot call the view function on an `internal` function, so, you just need to change the visibility of the mapping to `public`.

```js
mapping(bytes32 => string) public requestToCharacterName;
```

Otherwise, you can read directly from storage using something like [hardhat-storage-layout](https://hardhat.org/plugins/hardhat-storage-layout.html).

Comment: i am using hardhat as well. i hav a mapping as follows-

mapping(uint => Post) posts; 
where Post is a struct
is there any way to console.log the "posts" OR posts[0]? using hardhat console.log?

Comment: Yes, you can `console.log` it, but you'd need to log out a type that console.log accepts. It won't accept a `Post` type.

Comment: Thanks Patrick for the reply! so essentially we cannot log it since "console.logX" where logX supports "Post" doesn't exist?